# Replace r\n with \n in exception:format=@

Tags: nlog

When I use this in nlog config:

```
<attribute name="Exception" encode="false" layout="${exception:format=@}"/>
```

The json string includes "\r\n". How can I replace it with "\n"?

Many thanks!
Gunnar

Comment: Have you tried to use the `${replace:searchFor=\\\\r\\\\n:replaceWith=\\\\n:inner=${exception:format=@}}`? https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Replace-Layout-Renderer

Comment: I did, but I forgot the double \\ Thanks a lot Rolf Kristensen! :-)

Comment: Posted my comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use this:

```
${replace:searchFor=\\\\r\\\\n:replaceWith=\\\\n:inner=${exception:format=@}}
```

See also: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Replace-Layout-Renderer

Comment: Yes and it worked. Thanks a lot! I did try it before asking, but with wrong number of "\".  Before I was trying to replace "\r\n" but it worked when I used "\\r\\n" :-)